# modify raster metadata in qgis to change raster coordinates

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, editing, metadata

I have two rasters of the same place, however they differ 3metres between them. So I want to change the metadata of one of them, to match the coordinates of the other one. (they both use the same projection and coordinate system, its just a raster geolocation issue)

I've read that this can be done using "gdal_translate -a_ullr X-coordinate Y-coordinate" but the command is failing.

Anyone knows an easy/fast way to change metadata coordinates in QGIS?

Comment: What exactly are you entering when you call gdal_translate, and what is the error message you get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in qgis under the raster>projections>assign projection you may find a gui to the gdal_translate command